# Subclassing a Method Returning instancetype

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, sprite-kit, skspritenode, instancetype

I have a custom class which is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`.  I am trying to override the `spriteNodeWithColor:size:` method which returns `instancetype`.  I try this:

```
 -(instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size{
     self.color = color;
     self.size = size;

     //do other setup stuff here
     return self;
}
```

but **it crashes every time**.  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If it crashes, what error is reported? Where does this error occur?

Comment: The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x240)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `super`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size {
    self = [super initWithColor:color size:size];

    if (self) {
      // do other setup stuff here
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm....I thought I had tried this before. It works now, so thanks for reminding me.  I think I've a bit too long of a programming session.

Comment: Yes I just did. I was meaning to do that, but had to go out.

Comment: How do you subclass one of the class-level methods that return instancetype?